# Gaussian curvature on a regular surface induced by a graph

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, curvature

Let's assume we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and we have a $f(x,y) \in C^\infty$. Then a regular surface is given by $$M:=\{(x,y,z,)\in\mathbb{R}^3 | f(x,y)=z\},$$ and clearly we have a local parametrisation given by $$X(u,v) := (u,v,f(u,v)).$$

I now want to calculate the integral over the Gaussian curvature using the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

My idea is that $$F(u,v,w):=X(u,v)+we_3$$
is a diffeomorphism between the $xy-plane$ and $M$ so the Euler characteristic of $M$ should be $$\chi(M)=2.$$

> Using now the global Gauss-Bonnet theorem we get that for **all** $M$ induced by such an $f$ the integral over the Gaussian curvature satisfies
>   $$\int_M KdA = 2\pi\chi(M)=4\pi.$$

But this seems strange to me because if we take for example the cone induced for $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},~~~and~~~z>0$$
$M$ should be flat and therefore the integral should vanish.

I am thankful for every helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two issues with your cone example:

1. $M$ is only a regular submanifold if zero is a regular value of the level set function $g(x,y,z) = f(x,y)-z$.  This is not the case for the cone since $g$ is not differentiable at the cone point $(0,0,0)$. This is not a fatal issue, since one might imagine "rounding off" the cone's tip; however
2. Gauss-Bonnet holds only for *compact* surfaces, which the cone is not. You could restrict yourself to a graph over some compact region of the plane, in which case Gauss-Bonnet will hold, though you will need to include the geodesic curvature terms that arise at the boundary of the domain.

Comment: +1. Of course, even if you round off the cone point, there will be some Gaussian curvature there that you need to account for.

Comment: okay, lets forget about the cone example.
What about the rest of the proof? This would still be an interessting result for me.

Could there be a Problem with the $F$? My idea to show that it is a diffeomorphism was with the invers function theorem. But this only gives us a local diffeomorphism. Is the Euler characteristic still preserved?

Comment: @Bara No, there is a fundamental problem here: *any* graph over the entire plane will not be compact. As I mention above, probably the simplest correction is to restrict $f$ to a bounded region of the plane, but then you will still need to account for the boundary curvature.

Comment: oh, I see what you mean. So if we restrict $f$, in a way that $M$ is bounded. 
Why is there boundary curvature popping up? Is $M$ in this case not compact since it is closed and bounded?